# Can we change the base address of an array through a pointer to array using brute force?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Somebody wrote the following C program and asked why gcc allows "to change the base address of an array". He was aware that the code is terrible but still wanted to know. I found the question interesting enough, because the relationship between arrays and pointers in C is subtle (behold the use of the address operator on the array! "Why would anybody do that?"), confusing and consequently often misunderstood. The question was deleted but I thought I ask it again, with proper context and — as I hope — a proper answer to go with it. Here is the original prog.

```
static char* abc = "kj";

void fn(char**s)
{
   *s = abc;
}

int main() 
{
   char str[256];
   fn(&str);
}
```

It compiles with gcc (with warnings), links and runs. What happens here? Can we change the base address of an array by taking its address, casting it to pointer to pointer (after all arrays are almost pointers in C, aren't they) and assigning to it?

Comment: for posterity, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660493/assigning-to-a-char-array-using-assignment-operator-and-double-pointers) is the deleted question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program doesn't change the "base address" of the array. It's not even trying to.

What you pass to fn is the address of a chunk of 256 characters in memory. It is numerically identical to the pointer which `str` would decay to in other expressions, only differently typed. Here, the array really stays an array -- applying the address operator to an array is one of the instances where an array does not decay to a pointer. Incrementing `&str`, for example, would increase it numerically by 256. This is important for multi dimensional arrays which, as we know, actually are one-dimensional arrays of arrays in C. Incrementing the first index of a "2-dimensional" array must advance the address to the start of the next "chunk" or "row".

Now the catch. As far as fn is concerned, the address you pass points to a location which contains another address. That is not true; it points to a sequence of characters. Printing that byte sequence interpreted as a pointer reveals the 'A' byte values, 65 or 0x41.

fn, however, thinking that the memory pointed to contains an address, overwrites it with the address where "kj" is residing in memory. Since there is enough memory allocated in str to hold an address, the assignment succeeds and results in a usable address at that location.

It should be noted that this is, of course, not guaranteed to work. The most common cause for failure should be alignment issues -- `str` is, I think, not required to be aligned properly for a pointer value. The standard mandates that arguments to functions must be assignment-compatible with the parameter declarations. Arbitrary pointer types cannot be assigned to each other (one needs to go through void pointers for that, or cast).

**Edit:** david.pfx pointed out that (even with a proper cast) the code invokes **undefined behaviour.** The standard requires access to objects through compatible lvalues (including referenced pointers) in section 6.5/7 of the latest public draft. When casting properly and compiling with  `gcc -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 ...` gcc warns about the "type punning". The rationale is that the compiler should be free to assume that incompatible pointers do not modify the same memory region; here it is not required to assume that fn changes the contents of str. This enables the compiler to optimize away reloads (e.g. from memory to register) which would otherwise be necessary. This will play a role with optimization; a likely example where a debugging session would fail to reproduce the error (namely if the program being debugged would be compiled without optimization for debugging purposes). That being said, I'd be surprised if a non-optimizing compiler would produce unexpected results here, so I let the rest of the answer stand as is.--

I have inserted a number of debug printfs to illustrate what's going on. A live example can be seen here: http://ideone.com/aL407L.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
static char* abc = "kj";

// Helper function to print the first bytes a char pointer points to
void printBytes(const char *const caption, const char *const ptr)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("%s: {", caption);
    for( i=0; i<sizeof(char *)-1; ++i)
    {
        printf("0x%x,", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf( "0x%x ...}\n", ptr[sizeof(char *)-1] );
}

// What exactly does this function do?
void fn(char**s) {
    printf("Inside fn: Argument value is %p\n", s);
    printBytes("Inside fn: Bytes at address above are", (char *)s);

    // This throws. *s is not a valid address.
    // printf("contents: ->%s<-\n", *s);

    *s = abc;
    printf("Inside fn: Bytes at address above after assignment\n");
    printBytes("           (should be address of \"kj\")", (char *)s);

    // Now *s holds a valid address (that of "kj").
    printf("Inside fn: Printing *s as string (should be kj): ->%s<-\n", *s);

}


int main() {
   char str[256];

   printf("size of ptr: %zu\n", sizeof(void *));
   strcpy(str, "AAAAAAAA"); // 9 defined bytes

   printf("addr of \"kj\": %p\n", abc);
   printf("str addr: %p (%p)\n", &str, str);
   printBytes("str contents before fn", str);

   printf("------------------------------\n");
   // Paramter type does not match! Illegal code
   // (6.5.16.1 of the latest public draft; incompatible
   // types for assignment).
   fn(&str);

   printf("------------------------------\n");

   printBytes("str contents after fn (i.e. abc -- note byte order!): ", str);
   printf("str addr after fn -- still the same! --: %p (%p)\n", &str, str);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder how you were in time to answer with such a long post when the question was asked 6 minutes ago and your answer appeared also 6 minuts ago?!!!  To enter only the program code will take more than 1 minute.

Comment: Well, Ctrl-V takes 1/100th ;-). And I detected here that when I ask a question, SO gives me the opportunity to write the answer right away together with the question. This self-Q/A pattern is one of the supported formats for SO so that people can share their insights (you cannot write an answer without a question, I think). This is the first time I have tried it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this has been copy-pasted from another question which has now been deleted

Comment: @MattMcNabb The OP's code I left unchanged (except for formatting), but I reframed the question.

Comment: @Peter Schneider Could you make a fictitious edition of the question that I could remove its down-vote?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you can actually make your own fictitious edit in order to enable that (just put in the edit description why you did it)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow :-) Maybe now you can upvote again... not that it's that important, but thanks.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I did one just now (although Peter did simultaneously, ho hum)

Answer (score 7):

**It cannot work (even theoretically), because arrays are not pointers:**

---

- `int arr[10]`:

  - Amount of memory used is `sizeof(int)*10` bytes
  - The values of `arr` and `&arr` are necessarily identical
  - `arr` points to a valid memory address, but cannot be set to point to another memory address

---

- `int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*10)`:

  - Amount of memory used is `sizeof(int*) + sizeof(int)*10` bytes
  - The values of `ptr` and `&ptr` are not necessarily identical (in fact, they are mostly different)
  - `ptr` can be set to point to both valid and invalid memory addresses, as many times as you will

Comment: Well, the O-OP (not me) was puzzled by the fact that you can take the address of the array, dereference it and assign to that (after effectively casting it). He expected that that would change the "value" like with other pointers, as in `(*(&x)) = 1`. Since that "value" was the array he thought he changes the array, somehow (not its contents). In my answer I dissected the effect of an address operator applied to an array, the interpretation of the resulting argument value within `fn` after the type conversion, and the effects on the involved values.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: You've got me puzzled here. I gave you a +1 because I found the question interesting. Then I noticed that you were also the one who answered it (from the first comment to the answer), which is a bit weird I have to say, but that alright as far as I'm concerned... In any case, now you're saying "O-OP (not me) was puzzled". What does "O-OP" mean, and why do you refer to yourself as "not me"???

Comment: I used the "answer your own question" format for spreading wisdom ;-). It's not that uncommon; SO actually provides an option for editing your answer together with the question, which I was not aware of until today. That makes the OP's own answer appear first.-- As I explained in the question, it is based on one which a different user asked and then deleted. That person would have been the "Original Original Poster", or O-OP. It wasn't me. I'm the OP in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is simply Undefined Behaviour.

The parameter to the function is declared as pointer-to-pointer-to-char. The argument passed to it is pointer-to-array-of-256-char. The standard permits conversions between one pointer and another but since the object that s points to is not a pointer-to-char, dereferencing the pointer is Undefined Behaviour.

n1570 S6.5.3.2/4:

> If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is
>   undefined.

It is futile to speculate how Undefined Behaviour will play out on different implementations. It's just plain wrong.

---

Just to be clear, the UB is in this line:

```
*s=abc;
```

The pointer `s` does not point to an object of the correct type (`char*`), so the use of `*` is UB.

Comment: I do not think it is UB (well, gcc lets us pass the wrong pointer type which strictly spoken would require a cast, but let's assume a cast when calling `fn()`). The value passed is not invalid; it's a valid pointer to the array. Dereferencing it is well defined, if the alignment requirements are met. Cf n1570, 6.3.2.3/7: "A pointer to an object type may be [explicitly, P.S.] converted to a pointer to a different object type." The paragraph then discusses alignment issues and the behaviour when converting to char *, but it does not restrict the target pointer type.

Comment: Also note that the code never dereferences `*s` (e.g. tries to read `**s`) which would be illegal and crash on systems with memory protection, at least before `abc` was assigned to `*s`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: `*s=abc` is UB as per the standard. It matters not whether you call it 'dereferences' or not (I do). See edit.

Comment: Oh I see. Took me a while -- the standard is not well cross-referenced. It could mention that while arbitrary pointer conversions are allowed (the 6.3.2.3/7 above), you cannot do anything with the result (6.5/7: "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: — a type compatible with the effective type of the object [...]." (Plus signed/qualified derivates, character types and compatible unions.) Since it is a "shall" and not a constraint, I assume that it is indeed UB, although I'd have preferred it to be un*specified*.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I see difficulty in deciding which 'object' it is that is having its stored value accessed and how. I find the `*` para easier to understand.

Comment: Well, the pargraph you cite ("If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer ..."), is imho not applicable. The value assigned to the pointer is not invalid -- on the contrary, it's the valid address of str. The issue is more subtle: The pointer has been converted to a different, incompatible type, and the memory it points to is then accessed. That appears to be generally forbidden in modern C, as per 6.5/7. The rationale is that certain optimizations (skip a load from memory) assume that there is no intervening access through a differently typed pointer.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I think it's an invalid value for that type of pointer. I'll stand by my answer. If have another view, perhaps you should write your own answer.